# monotone function of operators / matrices

Tags: functional-analysis

Assume we have increasing function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. I know its not always true that if we take operators or matrices $x,y$ then $x \le y \implies f(x) \le f(y)$ - for that I need operator monotone function. But what if I assume that $\vert\vert x\vert\vert_\infty \le K$? Does it imply that $f(x) \le f(K)$?

Comment: How do you define $\|x\|_\infty$ for a matrix $x$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want $x$ to be self-adjoint. In this case, the answer is yes and follows from the spectral theorem. The map $\sigma(x)\to B(H),\,f\mapsto f(x)$ is a unital $\ast$-homomorphism. In particular, it preserves the order. Hence $f\leq f(K)1$ implies $f(x)\leq f(K)1$.

Comment: Note that OP hasn't defined $\|x\|_\infty$. If thesy mean the usual operator norm, then your answer is fine.

Comment: usual operator norm, yes